# How to make sure a drawn object obscures another if both using same vertex locations?

Tags: opengl

Im working on an OpenGL project where i have to draw a colored gridblock as well as (white/black) lines bordering each cell in the block.

The vertices locations composing the cells are the same as the ones used for the lines(borders)..

If I use the same vertices to draw both the cells and the lines, will the lines be obscured by the faces or is it the other way around?

How do i make sure that the lines will be always visible ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends on the depthfunc. with GL_LESS later primitives draw over earlier primitives if the later primitives are located before the earlier primitives. With GL_LEQUAL, the later primitives get drawn if they are not behind (i.e. same postition or before) the earlier primitives.

Thus you can either draw the lines after the cells using GL_LEQUAL or draw the cells after the lines with GL_LESS.

If you use different shaders, you might want to declare gl_Position as invariant, to ensure that the computed coordinates are exactly equal.